# How to launch/run the generated binary using ndk toolchain?

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, ndk-build

I am using the cmake commands to build a C++ code using ndk toolchain as discussed in this [link](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake)

Here is the copy of my Cmake command:

```
cmake ${SRC_DIR} \
        -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${NDK_HOME}/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
        -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-30  \
        -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=${HOME}/las_android/lib  \
        -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=${HOME}/las_android/output
```

It generate the binary file in *${HOME}/las_android/output* directory. My question is that how I can launch/run the generated binary file on an android device or simulator.

Comment: Suggest you read [Android NDK - Concepts](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/concepts)

Comment: Thanks @RichardCritten for the suggestion. Can I consider the generated binary file as an Android ABI? Do we need a NativeActivity class to launch the binary of C++ code on an Andorid device?

Comment: The Android NDK only officially supports the creation of dynamic libraries that are then run from Java/Kotlin or via [Native activities](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/concepts#naa) which a built in Java application.  Note your NDK compiled code has to follow the API convention(s) to interact with the Native Activity see the link above and the Google sample code.